# What is the right size of icon for application list?

Tags: c#, icons, windows-phone-7, marketplace

I am a bit confused about the size of icon that appears in app list.

MSDN says

> The small mobile app tile that you want displayed on the phone app
> list. Games must use the large mobile app tile in place of the small
> mobile app tile. The small mobile app tile must be a 62 x 62 pixel PNG
> file.

But the Visual Studio Market place test kit says

[image]

Is it a bug?

I think it must be 62 x 62 because it is the icon size that comes with template mobile project but I want to make sure my assumption is correct

Comment: this will not affect ur app just go for it. its your inner page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They want a 99 x 99 version of your 62 x 62 image.  The little 62x62 that's compiled into your .xap is the one that will show up on the phone any way so this one is just for your app's details page.

Comment: so does it mean statement `This image is used in phone application list` is incorrect?

Comment: It means the phone application list on the Marketplace, not on the phone itself.

Comment: hmmm. Only thing that confused me was the fact that in every other image word `MarketPlace` is explicitly mentioned but no in this particular case